# Improve the performance on inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, inner-join

I have a query Like this :

```
SELECT 
    Mnum, Label , Lvalue ,[Property Type] , RowID, ColumnID, DisplayOrder
FROM
    (SELECT 
        a.Mnum as Mnum, -- 420 fields go here
     FROM   -- 51 joins go here
    ) AS MainQuery 
UNPIVOT (LabelValue FOR LabelName IN ( --420 fields go here ))
AS UnpvtQuery 

INNER JOIN 
    ReportFieldsLookup rfl on rfl.label = LabelName and rfl.PropType = [PropertyType]
```

The break down of the above shown query is as follows:

A portion of the above mentioned query which will perform inner join on multiple tables (exactly 51 inner joins) and will spit out 420 columns for each ID. And I perform an Unpivot action on this resultant table. Which will result in 420 rows for each ID.

```
SELECT 
    Mnum, Label , Lvalue ,[Property Type] , RowID, ColumnID, DisplayOrder
FROM
   (SELECT 
        a.Mnum as Mnum, -- 420 columns go here
    FROM   -- 51 joins go here
   ) AS MainQuery 
 UNPIVOT (  LabelValue FOR LabelName IN ( --420 fields go here ))
```

The result table will contain the following columns:

```
    Mnum          varchar
    LabelName     varchar
    Lvalue        varchar
    PropertyType  varchar
```

Sample data :

```
8045    Assoc Amenities         N/A         C/C
8045    Assoc Fees Include      n/a         C/C
8045    Assoc Pet Rules         N/A         C/C
8045    Attached/Detached       Detached    C/C
8045    Avail for Lease         No          C/C
8045    BRELA                   No          C/C
6012    Assoc Amenities         N/A         C/C
6012    Assoc Fees Include      n/a         C/C
6012    Assoc Pet Rules         N/A         C/C
6012    Attached/Detached       Detached    C/C
6012    Avail for Lease         No          C/C
6012    BRELA                   No          C/C
7129    Assoc Amenities         AV          SFR
7129    Assoc Fees Include      yes         SFR
7129    Assoc Pet Rules         N/A         SFR
7129    Change Date             N/A         SFR
3278    Assoc Amenities         Yes         lnd
3278    Assoc Fees Include      0           lnd
3278    Assoc Pet Rules         N/A         lnd
3278    Directions              abc         lnd     
3278    Disclosure              aff         lnd
```

When I run the above shown portion of the query with 24 `Mnum's` as input it takes me about 6 sec to execute the query.

Now I have another table (`ReportFieldsLookup`) which contains the following columns :

```
rownum   bigint,
Aid      varchar
reportid bigint
Label    varchar
PropType  varchar
DisplayOrder bigint
```

Sample data :

```
1   101 1   Assoc Amenities         C/C     1   
2   101 1   Assoc Fees Include      C/C     2   
3   101 1   Assoc Pet Rules         C/C     3   
4   101 1   Avail for Lease         C/C     4   
5   101 1   Attached/Detached       C/C     5
6   101 1   BRELA                   C/C     6
7   101 1   Assoc Amenities         SFR     1   
8   101 1   Assoc Fees Include      SFR     2   
9   101 1   Assoc Pet Rules         SFR     3   
10  101 1   Change Date             SFR     4
11  101 1   Assoc Amenities         lnd     1   
12  101 1   Assoc Fees Include      lnd     2   
13  101 1   Assoc Pet Rules         lnd     3   
14  101 1   Directions              lnd     4
15  101 1   Disclosure              lnd     5
```

and I am trying to join the above shown two tables.

```
INNER JOIN 
    ReportFieldsLookup rfl ON rfl.label = LabelName AND rfl.PropType = [PropertyType]
```

The result table :

```
8045    Assoc Amenities         N/A         C/C     1
8045    Assoc Fees Include      n/a         C/C     2
8045    Assoc Pet Rules         N/A         C/C     3
8045    Attached/Detached       Detached    C/C     4
8045    Avail for Lease         No          C/C     5
8045    BRELA                   No          C/C     6
6012    Assoc Amenities         N/A         C/C     1
6012    Assoc Fees Include      n/a         C/C     2
6012    Assoc Pet Rules         N/A         C/C     3
6012    Attached/Detached       Detached    C/C     4
6012    Avail for Lease         No          C/C     5
6012    BRELA                   No          C/C     6
7129    Assoc Amenities         AV          SFR     1
7129    Assoc Fees Include      yes         SFR     2
7129    Assoc Pet Rules         N/A         SFR     3
7129    Change Date             N/A         SFR     4
3278    Assoc Amenities         Yes         lnd     1
3278    Assoc Fees Include      0           lnd     2
3278    Assoc Pet Rules         N/A         lnd     3
3278    Directions              abc         lnd     4
3278    Disclosure              aff         lnd     5
```

It's taking about 30+ secs.

What should I do to reduce the execution time?

Answer (score 1):

First thing you could do is make sure you have indexes in all of the tables on the columns being referenced to make the joins.

Assuming that's already done and you need more performance, that's a lot of inner joins, so I'd make an indexed view on the `MainQuery` portion of your code:

```
-- Create a view from the query
CREATE VIEW dbo.MnumIndexedView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
SELECT a.Mnum as Mnum, -- 420 fields go here
  FROM   -- 51 joins go here
GO

-- Index the view
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_cl_mnumindexedview
ON dbo.MnumIndexedView(Mnum);
GO

-- Your new query, this time using the indexed view.
SELECT   Mnum, Label, Lvalue, [Property Type], RowID, ColumnID, DisplayOrder
FROM     dbo.MnumIndexedView WITH (NOEXPAND)
UNPIVOT (LabelValue FOR LabelName IN ( --420 fields go here ))
AS
INNER JOIN ReportFieldsLookup rfl 
        ON rfl.label = LabelName AND rfl.PropType = [PropertyType]
```

You can't put the whole thing in an indexed view as I believe that `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` are not supported for indexed views. However, persisting the data from the many inner joins should hopefully get you some better performance.

Note that this needs [some additional options to be enabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx#Restrictions) as SQL Server can be a little picky when it comes to getting it to allow indexed view creation.

Also note the use of `WITH (NOEXPAND)` in the query on the indexed view. In non-enterprise versions of SQL Server this is necessary otherwise the optimizer will just query the underlying tables and you won't see any benefit.

Comment: Whoah.... slow down! Why go straight to indexed views without establishing whether basic indexes even exist?

Comment: Ok I added a part at the beginning to make sure he's got indexes on all of the columns being referenced in the join. But if he goes too crazy with doing that, it may end up being just as much of a write performance hit/DBMS overhead to establish all of those indexes (not to mention it's a large amount of work) as it would be to just have done an indexed view in the first place.